How to shut down the resource tracker after running Python's ProcessPoolExecutor
I have been using the ProcessPoolExecutor in concurrent.futures for a while, but I recently noticed that jobs with concurrent processes, which were submitted to a cluster batch queue, were never properly shut down after completion. The reason appears to be that, although the parallel processes completed succesfully, a subprocess created by ProcessPoolExecutor is still active even after the pool itself is shut down.
I know that people expect a minimal reproducible example, so here is some code.
import time

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

def test_function(i):
    time.sleep(20)
    return i

def test_pool():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
        futures = []
        result = []
        for i in range(6):
            futures.append(executor.submit(test_function, i))
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            result.append(future.result())

    print(len(result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_pool()

The complication is that, if you run this from the command line, the code will complete as expected. To see the problem, you have to embed the functions in an importable module and run the test_pool function in a debugger. I ran this in an interactive IPython shell within the NeXpy application. In VS Code, I see the following:
These are the processes before running test_pool.

These are the processes during the run. Note that there are seven additional subprocesses, one for each process in the pool plus an additional one (9812).

These are the processes after the run. The pool subprocesses have been successfully removed, leaving the additional one (9812), which causes the problem.

Further debugging shows that the additional process is a resource tracker, which is launched when ProcessPoolExecutor uses the 'spawn' method. However, it is not removed when the executor is shut down, and I can’t see what additional steps I can use to remove it. This would not be a problem except that the existence of this subprocess seems to prevent batch queues from shutting the job down.
So my question is whether anyone knows how to close the resource tracker process.
Edit (2024/5/11): It turns out that if I force the ProcessPoolExecutor to use 'fork' instead of 'spawn' as the context, the additional process is not created. I had thought that 'fork' was the default context on MacOS, but apparently not. The additional process is a resource tracker, which is only needed when using the 'spawn' mode. I have edited the question to reflect this new information.

Your code creates exactly 6 subprocesses, but the listing shows 7 (Subprocess 9812...9818).  I strongly suspect that the extra one comes from your environment, since it can't possibly result from the code you are showing.  So I'm not convinced that there is a real problem in the first place, at least not one that your test program has demonstrated.  If you think the problem comes from a subprocess creating a second subprocess, why not write that into your test program?

Second comment: when you run the program from the command line, can you use operating system tools to check on stray subprocesses that may have been launched but not cleaned up?  If you can't find any of those, that would be further evidence that you haven't correctly identified the real issue with your original program.

As I wrote in my penultimate paragraph, I know exactly when the additional process is created because I tracked its appearance in the debugger. When initializing the ProcessPoolExecutor, it creates an attribute called '_call_queue', as an instance of a '_SafeQueue' class, which is defined by the ProcessPoolExecutor code as a subclass of the Python Queue. Initializing the Python Queue then creates a semaphore lock, at which exact point the new subprocess appears. So it does result from the code I showed. That is not in doubt. What I don't know is how to remove the subprocess.

I should have pointed out that it is the multiprocessing.queues.Queue class that is subclassed. I presume the regular Queue class does not spawn any subprocesses.
